# How can i add a keyboard programmatically to keyboards list in iOS 8 or iOS 7

Tags: ios7, keyboard, ios8

As you know we can add a keyboard by following these steps manually: Settings -> General -> keyboard -> keyboards -> add a keyboard .

I want to do that programmatically by using an UIButton in my app. Is it possible?

Thanks...